# Solution to system of non linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

what is the best way  to solve this 
system of equations:

$$ax^2 +by^2-2y=0$$
$$axy+byz-z=0$$
$$ay^2+bz^2-c=0$$ 
Solve for x,y,z where a,b,c are constants.

Comment: Are you sure of the second equation ?

Comment: "best way" in what sense ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry made a typo. Edited.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Easiest. Also would best great to know if there is procedure to approach such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Extract $y$ from the second equation to get $$y=\frac{z}{a x+b z}$$ Plug in the third equation which is a quadratic in $x$; the solutions are $$x_{\pm}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{a^3 c z^2-a^3 b z^4}-a b^2 z^3+a b c z}{a^2( b z^2- c)}$$ You are left with a nasty equation in $z$ using the first equation.

I suppose that you have four sets of solutions.

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation,

$$x=\frac{1-by}{ay}z.$$

Plug this in the first,

$$\frac{(1-by)^2}{ay^2}z^2+by^2-2y=0.$$

Then you can eliminate $z^2$ with the third, giving

$$\frac{ay^2(2y-by^2)}{(1-by)^2}=\frac{c-ay^2}b,$$
and by magic the equation simplifies to
$$(a-cb^2)y^2+2bcy-c=0.$$

Now the problem has turned to the resolution of a quadratic equation in a single unknown. There are at most two real solutions in $y$. $z$ and $x$ easily follow from $y$, for a total of four distinct solution sets.

Generally speaking, you can address such problems by putting the system in a triangular form, leading to higher degree univariate polynomials. (The degree reflects the number of possible solutions.) Good root-finding numerical methods are available.

There are systematic approaches (involving Gröbner bases), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations, but this remains a difficult topic.

Comment: Shouldn't it be (c-ay^2)/b when we substitute z^2?

Comment: @Akhilesh1990: quite right. I am fixing the typo.

Comment: Much better than my junk !

Comment: Thank you so much! this was very helpful. @YvesDaoust

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yep, leaving radicals called for trouble. And then it turns out that the problem is quite tractable :)

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: "the best case scenario": can you elaborate ?

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: hem, can you elaborate ? What is the not-best case ?

Comment: My case is the worst !

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: haha.